# Extract everything between 2 strings in snowflake using regular expression

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, regexp-substr

I have a json like below stored in `col1` of a `snowflake table` `table1` from which I want to extract the `dump` portion into a column `dump` in a snowflake table `table2`. I am trying to use regular expression to do it using `regexp_substr` but am not able to form the correct pattern.

```
TABLE1.COL1
------------
...
"c_n": "abc",
  "dump": {
    "d_k": "c_s_s",
    "d_v": "{\"abc\":null,\"efg\":3,\"mrc\":3,\"er\":3,\"ff\":{\"ie\":false},\"slm\":false,\"sld\":false,\"lang\":\"hi\"}",
    "date": "20001111112720",
    "fs": "i_t",
    "id": 0000,
    "i_c": null,
    "i_l": null,
    "prof": 0,
    "s_t": "2000-09-11 10:27:20.450924",
    "s_i": "abc57fhg",
    "src": "test_*"
  },
  "ec": "p-ap-p-cl",
...
```

The logic I am applying is to extract everything in between `"dump":` and `,"ec"` so that I can get below output:

```
TABLE2.DUMP
------------
{
    "d_k": "c_s_s",
    "d_v": "{\"abc\":null,\"efg\":3,\"mrc\":3,\"er\":3,\"ff\":{\"ie\":false},\"slm\":false,\"sld\":false,\"lang\":\"hi\"}",
    "date": "20001111112720",
    "fs": "i_t",
    "id": 0000,
    "i_c": null,
    "i_l": null,
    "prof": 0,
    "s_t": "2000-09-11 10:27:20.450924",
    "s_i": "abc57fhg",
    "src": "test_*"
  }
```

Can someone please help in building the correct regular expression for this use case as I am  fairly new with using regexp family of functions.
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you want to use regex when Snowflake allows you to select the elements in a json string

Comment: The example above is not a valid JSON

Comment: I think it's safe to assume, given the presence of the ellipses in the original question, that we're just looking at a snippet of a larger, presumably valid, JSON value

Comment: Possible but, even `dump` section itself is not valid json

Answer (score 0):

The example data is not a valid json so json parsing will not work if the source data is formatted like the example.

This can be achieved with `SUBSTRING` and `CHARINDEX` assuming "ec" always follows "dump"

```
WITH table1 (col1) AS (
SELECT * FROM VALUES
('{"c_n": "abc",
  "dump": {
    "d_k": "c_s_s",
    "d_v": "{\"abc\":null,\"efg\":3,\"mrc\":3,\"er\":3,\"ff\":{\"ie\":false},\"slm\":false,\"sld\":false,\"lang\":\"hi\"}",
    "date": "20001111112720",
    "fs": "i_t",
    "id": 0000,
    "i_c": null,
    "i_l": null,
    "prof": 0,
    "s_t": "2000-09-11 10:27:20.450924",
    "s_i": "abc57fhg",
    "src": "test_*"
  },"ec": "p-ap-p-cl"
  }'))
)
SELECT SUBSTRING(col1,
            -- position of dump
            CHARINDEX('"dump": {', col1) + 8, 
            -- length of the string between dump and ec
            NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',"ec":', col1), 0) - (CHARINDEX('"dump": {', col1) + 8) 
        ) AS dump_section
FROM table1
```

The above SQL assumes the line with `ec` is formatted as `,ec` per the question even though provided sample doesn't follow this.

Answer (score 0):

So if I alter the json, to not have the "prior" and "later" rowss, and escape the slashes, so the SQL parser correctly leaves those in the stringified `"d_v"`

and thus can parse this as JSON, I can then just "access" the JSON element, and not assume the JSON which does not define order of member as important, will just work (tm):

```
select 
    parse_json($1) as col1
    ,col1:dump as dump
from values
('{"c_n": "abc",
  "dump": {
    "d_k": "c_s_s",
    "d_v": "{\\"abc\\":null,\\"efg\\":3,\\"mrc\\":3,\\"er\\":3,\\"ff\\":{\\"ie\\":false},\\"slm\\":false,\\"sld\\":false,\\"lang\\":\\"hi\\"}",
    "date": "20001111112720",
    "fs": "i_t",
    "id": 0000,
    "i_c": null,
    "i_l": null,
    "prof": 0,
    "s_t": "2000-09-11 10:27:20.450924",
    "s_i": "abc57fhg",
    "src": "test_*"
  },
  "ec": "p-ap-p-cl"
  }')
```

dump comes out, just as expected:

[image]